# Delete all duplicates of record in collection - MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, collections

I have a mongoDB collection that is like this (below). As you can see it has a number of duplicate records, with maybe a few attributes that differ. Now in my collection there are plus 18000 results, I need to remove all of the duplicates that are in there. I doesn't matter which one I keep, I just need no dupes. Can any one help or point me in the right direction?

```
{
  commonName: "Lionel Messi",
  firstName: "Lionel",
  lastName: "Messi",
  rating: 97
},{
  commonName: "Lionel Messi",
  firstName: "Lionel",
  lastName: "Messi",
  rating: 96
},{
  commonName: "Lionel Messi",
  firstName: "Lionel",
  lastName: "Messi",
  rating: 92
},{
  commonName: "Jamie Vardy",
  firstName: "Jamie",
  lastName: "Vardy",
  rating: 82
},{
  commonName: "Jamie Vardy",
  firstName: "Jamie",
  lastName: "Vardy",
  rating: 86
}
```

Comment: You can create a new collection, that is the result of some data cleaning operations, check the data, and after that you can rename the collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `aggregate` to clean your data, and then use `$out` to write a collection, or even overwrite your current collection:

```
db.players.aggregate([
  { 
    $group : {
      _id : { commonName: "$commonName"  },
      commonName: {$first: "$commonName"},
      firstName: {$first: "$firstName"},
      lastName: {$first: "$lastName"},
      rating: {$first: "$rating"},
    }
  },
  { $project : { _id:0, commonName:1, firstName:1, lastName:1, rating:1 } },
  { $out : "players" }
])
```

**Note**: If you want to write a new collection use `{ $out : "newCollection" }`

Comment: Amazing I will give something like this a try! Sounds like a silly question but where would I run a script like this? In the terminal whilst in the players collection?

Comment: No silly question at all. I will run that script in the [MongoDB Shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/shell/client/)

Comment: Amazing, thanks. How come _id and has the same value as commonValue? Is _id what the aggregator is comparing the values to check if they are the same?

Comment: The `_id` field in the `$group` stage provides the criteria to group the documents, in you case, is "group all documents that have the same `commonName`"

Comment: @SamKelham If the answer prodive a solution to your problem, please accept/upvote.

Comment: I will do when I have implemented it :)

Answer (score 1):

Create temp collection with **unique index** of all the four fields, Then copy data from original collection to the temp collection, now temp collection should contain only unique records. after this you can clear original collection records and move records from temp to original collection

Answer (score 1):

You could clean your data by adding a unique index.
Depending on your mongoDB version you have two ways.

If your mongoDB version is 2.6 or older then you can run this command:

```
db.players.ensureIndex({'commonName' : 1, 'firstName' :1 }, {unique : true, dropDups : true})
```

If your version is newer then you could do something like this:

```
db.players.aggregate([
{ "$group": {
   "_id": { "commonName": "$commonName", "firstName": "$firstName"},
   "dups": { "$push": "$_id" },
   "count": { "$sum": 1 }
}},
{ "$match": { "count": { "$gt": 1 } }}
]).forEach(function(doc) {
       doc.dups.shift();
       db.events.remove({ "_id": {"$in": doc.dups }});
});

db.players.createIndex({"commonName":1 , "firstName": 1},
{unique:true})
```

Warning: You should first try this on some test data, just to be sure you are not removing important data that you want.